# How can I hide the last element in my container?

Tags: jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/Lyuz233f/1/

I want to hide only my last `hr` but I do not understand, why all my `hr`s are hidden:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center" style="margin-bottom:50px">
            <h4 class="uppercase mb16">Something</h4> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <div class="post-snippet mb64" style="margin-bottom:0px">
                <div style="text-align:justify">
                    <p>one</p>
                </div>
                <hr/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <div class="post-snippet mb64" style="margin-bottom:0px">
                <div style="text-align:justify">
                    <p>two</p>
                </div>
                <hr/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <div class="post-snippet mb64" style="margin-bottom:0px">
                <div style="text-align:justify">
                    <p>three</p>
                </div>
                <hr/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
  $( ".container hr:last-child" ).css({ display:"none"});
</script>
```

Comment: While the answers here are correct. I suggest learning nth-child and use css when possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this to hide last hr element:

```
$(".container hr:last" ).css({ display:"none"});
```

Here is the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lyuz233f/2/) implementing this solution.

Comment: The last-child selector is used to select the last child element of a parent. It cannot be used to select the last child element with a specific class under a given parent element.

Comment: @BharatsingParmar, please don't copy my answer. I didn't copied yours. Be fair dude.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for understanding. +1 for the answer.

Comment: @lonut +1 for your answer also.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is not working because when you're trying to select the `last-child` element of a given parent, this will look for direct descendents of that parent element, in this case `.container` element. Try selecting the last `.row` in `.container` and this will exemplify what I just said:

```js
$( ".container .row:last-child hr" ).css({ display:"none"});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center" style="margin-bottom:50px">
            <h4 class="uppercase mb16">Something</h4> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <div class="post-snippet mb64" style="margin-bottom:0px">
                <div style="text-align:justify">
                    <p>one</p>
                </div>
                <hr/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <div class="post-snippet mb64" style="margin-bottom:0px">
                <div style="text-align:justify">
                    <p>two</p>
                </div>
                <hr/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <div class="post-snippet mb64" style="margin-bottom:0px">
                <div style="text-align:justify">
                    <p>three</p>
                </div>
                <hr/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this solution as an alternative

```
$(".container hr:last" ).hide();
```

OR

```
$( ".container .row:last-child hr" ).hide();
```